# How using semicolon in a string

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an issue I don't know how to resolve. I did some research but I didn't find anything about it.

My problem is the following:

`sum(case when z.SICO_Subscribed_offers__c = "JOU;SE" then 1 else 0 end) = 1`
When I use a semicolon like this i a string I get the following error:

`⛔️An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: ';' is a reserved word and may not appear in your query.`

I absolutly need to write `;` in the string. What can I do ?

Thanks for help!!

Comment: "JOU;SE"  looks like a value rather than a column name. Shouldn't it be single-quoted rather than double-quoted?

Comment: SQL uses double quotes for delimited identifiers, e.g. `"column name"`, and single quotes for string literals, e.g. `'some text'`.

Comment: yeah I tried with single and double quote but I got the same result :/

Comment: This "while checking the query syntax" is not a Postgres error message - it seems the tool you are using doesn't understand this.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ok I see. I'm working on Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC)... Do you think there is an option for me to work around the problem?

Answer (score 1):

[String constants](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-CONSTANTS) need to be enclosed in single quotes `'` in SQL. Double quotes are for [identifiers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) `"JOU;SE"` is the name of a column.

```
sum(case when z.SICO_Subscribed_offers__c = 'JOU;SE' then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `"JOU \; SE"`, with the `\` sign.