# Remove all rows corresponding a specific ID if the value of a column match

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to delete all lines containing an ID if the value of a column in one of the rows matches the value sought

I have the following tables :

table1:

```
|   ID   |  |  offer    |
-------------------------
|   001  |  |  'SE;SL'  |
|   001  |  |   'WX'    |
|   001  |  |   'PW'    |

|   002  |  |   'WS'    |
|   002  |  |   'EL'    |

|   003  |  |   'SE'    |

|   004  |  |   'ZS'    |
|   004  |  |'PW;SE;ODL'|
```

```
SELECT  ID,
        offer
FROM table1
GROUP BY 
         ID,
         offer,
HAVING sum(case when offer LIKE '%SE%' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

For the moment, I am able to delete the line as follows:

```
|   ID   |  |  offer    |
-------------------------
|   001  |  |   'WX'    |
|   001  |  |   'PW'    |

|   002  |  |   'WS'    |
|   002  |  |   'EL'    |

|   004  |  |   'ZS'    |
```

Expected result

```
|   ID   |  |  offer    |
-------------------------
|   002  |  |   'WS'    |
|   002  |  |   'EL'    |
```

As you can see, I try to isolate all the IDs for which it appears at least once "SE" in one of the rows of the "offer" column.

I have tried many things, done several searches without success, if someone can help me understand!

Thanks so muchh

Comment: Fix your data model!  Do not store lists of strings as a string in a column.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I'm totaly agree with that. unfortunatly it's not my data model.. and I tell them (to the company I work on, (im still student))  that's not a good practice but they don't care ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use not exists

```
SELECT  ID,
        offer
FROM table1 t1
where not exists ( select 1 from  table1 t2 where t1.id=t2.id
                        and t2.offer like '%SE%')
```

Comment: it will work only if the `offer`s are 2 characters length. `'SEL;WS'` won't give the expected result

Answer (score 1):

With `NOT EXISTS` but you must check also the case the value you search is not part of another value. 
So concatenate both the offer column and the value with `;` at the start and at the end:

```
select id, offer
from table1 t
where not exists ( 
  select 1 from  table1 
  where 
    id=t.id
    and 
    ';' || offer || ';' like '%;SE;%'
)
```

**Edit**
 
Replace the last line with:

```
chr(59) || offer || chr(59) like '%' || chr(59) || 'SE' || chr(59) || '%'
```

Comment: thanks for you answer. I forget to specify that the tool I'm using does not support ';'. Do you thinks we can do this in an other way ? Regards,

Comment: What do you mean does not support `;`. It's just the delimeter  char in the values you want to check.

Comment: When I use semicolon i get this error : ```⛔️An error occurred while checking the query syntax. Errors: ';' is a reserved word and may not appear in your query.```

I'm working on Salesforce Marketing Cloud. And the tool who check my syntax don't like ```;```

Comment: Did you copy and paste the code as it is? Because when you use this `';'` (inside single quotes) there is no way  to get a syntax error. Isn't this Postgersql?

Comment: Yeah it's Postgresql. And yes, I know that's super weird actuelly but also I get the error when the semicolon is on a string .....
I have post the question before : here the link -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790035/how-using-semicolon-in-a-string/54790187#54790187